# owl carousel transition between images

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel for images on a page. During the transition the images jump, like they disapppearm shrink height on the screen.

all images are all the same size, this js at the bottom of the page

```
.carousel-main').owlCarousel({items:1,loop:true,lazyLoad:true,transitionStyle:"fade",autoplay:true,autoplayTimeout:4000,
```

autoHeight:true,margin:1,animateOut:'fadeOut',nav:true,dots:false,navText: ['',''],})

```html
<div class="row align-items-center my-1"><div class="col-12 col-carousel"><div class="owl-carousel carousel-main"><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com/carousel/1.jpg" alt="stuffed snowman"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com/carousel/2.jpg" alt="reindeer and snowman pillow"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com//carousel/3.jpg" alt="mini houses"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com/carousel/4.jpg" alt="silver sheep picture"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com//carousel/5.jpg" alt="By the Sea"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com/carousel/6.jpg" alt="table w globe lights"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://designedathome.com/carousel/7.jpg" alt="draperies"></div><div><img class="owl-lazy" data-src="carousel/8.jpg" alt="living room w lamp"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

[a link to the page it's on](https://designedathome.com/)

Do you need anymore info?

Comment: I assume the issue is gone when you disable `lazyLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix for this problem but don't blame me. It is not the best solution but at least it works. I have no clue why this happens in your case. Actually this shouldn't happen. But the issue is located at the `.owl-stage-outer` element because on every slide change the height (`style="height: xxx"`) is removed and readded to this div. Therefore the owl carousel jumps up and down because the `height:xxx` changes every image switch until all images are loaded.

I'm not sure but you might be able to fix this also with an updated configuration. Adjust `authHeight` or `lazyLoad` they are my first intuition because it only happens until all images are rotated through once. If nothing helps use the fix stated below:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Forcing a height like this and especially with `!important` is bad...but maybe someone else has a better solution or fix. But even thought better than nothing.

Comment: I added it to the css and then did a clear css cache and it works. I'll accept it as best answer after I see if more suggestions come in.

Comment: @mlegg glad to hear but I'm not happy with that fix ...  I hope someone else has a better suggestion :)

Comment: @mlegg actually no one had a better solution, interesting :D